# How to fire FB Pixel event with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, facebook-pixel

I'm setting up a FB pixel on a landing page. I have no access to Google Tag Manager and have no ability to add other scripts on the page outside the Facebook Pixel Code block.
My goal is to fire the "Search" event after 5 seconds, so I added the following code:

```html
<head>    
<!– Facebook Pixel Code –>
    <script>
        !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
            if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
                n.callMethod ?
                n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
            };
            if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n; n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = "2.0";
            n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
            t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
        }
        (window, document, "script", "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js");
        fbq("init", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        fbq("track", "PageView");
        setTimeout(function () { fbq("track", "Search"); }, 5000);
    </script>
    <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
</head>
```

For some reason, the "Search" event fired on page load, together with "PageView" and not after 5 seconds. 
On facebook pixel helper (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-pixel-helper/fdgfkebogiimcoedlicjlajpkdmockpc?hl=en) I see that "Search" fired on page load with orange color, and after 5 seconds it turns into green.

How can this event fire only after 5 seconds?

Comment: I tried it locally and it works fine. "PageView" is fired immediately and "Search" after 5 second without orange color. Have you installed AdBlock? Try to disable it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It did work as expected - FB pixel helper extenstion didn't work as expected. When looking at the chrome dev tools I could see that it works only after 5 sec.